# Pattern for configuring placement of graphic objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, graphics

I am looking for a pattern that applies to configuring placement of graphic objects.

Here's my problem:

I have some data objects with properties such as name, description, image etc.
I want to draw representations of these objects onto a canvas.

There are different "layouts" that can be applied. All the layout definitions are there at compile time.

In the layout description I want to be able to define the following for any of the object properties:

`size`: for text of course this doesn't mean the length/height of the whole text but of a character

`position`:

- either absolute to the starting point of the representation
- or relative to other displayed properties (e.g. `thisPropertyDisplay.x = anotherPropertyDisplay.x + anotherPropertyDisplay.length`)

Of course I could explicitly code the placement in n blocks/methods, one for each layout. Is there a better practise or an idiom how to implement this problem in Java?

What I actually want to do is I want to describe something like that:

```
property1.x = 0; property1.y = 0;
property2.x = property1.Endpoint.x; property2.y = property1.y;
property3.x = property1.Endpoint.x; property3.y = property2.Endpoint.y;
```

That definition is not explicitly coded in n Java methods, but there is one method able to parse all layout definition and apply them to the objects.

If the computation of the text size is beyond a useful pattern, just assume the length and height is always given.

Does that make sense? Is there a pattern / idiom name for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorator pattern seems to be the right one:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

The idea is you will have another class that will extend the behavior to handling the position and size information.

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't see the benefit of the decorator pattern for this problem.
Maybe I have to be more precise and maybe the narrowing of the question to graphics isn't helpful. I updated my original question. Does that make sense? Is that an example for a decorator? If not, is there another pattern / idiom describing it?

Comment: so, you want to extend your model to have position information, right?

Comment: I want to have variants of position information that can contain relative/computated values and I think it may be best to describe it in a more abstract level than to hard-code it in n Java methods.

Comment: And you don't want that information to be part of your model but extend it to have that information, right?

Comment: What would be the benefit of a Decorator? In contrast to my approach with a tiny parsing method?

Comment: Just oversaw your reply... Yes, I want to separate that information. But I also want to express it in a more abstract way and not in n explicit methods - whether they are in or outside the model.

Comment: Assume I have many properties and only a few layouts. Is Decorator a pragmatic approach?

Comment: It's a DSL for that. The benefits are related to the usage you will give to it. If that kind of code will be written by the end users, the other aproaches are a maintenance headache or you need to create thousands of those scripts, then go for it. But try to keep it simple.

Comment: Another choice is to have a Layout class that receives a Property in the constructor. Then, you can use something like `property1Layout.x(0)`